# Can I Use one model attribute two times in one view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, view, model

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with Framework 4.

I have one model with attribute firstname.

This is my model

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Investigator")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

This is my view where I am using:

In dropdownlist:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FirstName, Model.Names, "Enter New ...", new { @id = "ddlnames" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
```

In textbox:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
```

I am using it for dropdownlist selection and in dropdownlist I have one option to add new first name and on click on that I am giving option for add new First Name with text box having same name means (FirstName) as model of razor for new entry.

So my question is can I use that FirstName attribute of model for dropdownlist selection and for new entry as well.

I am getting value in dropdownlist selection but when I enter new first name value not coming.

Please someone who knows it help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short answer is no (the `DefaultModelBinder` will only bind the first name/pair value that is submitted (unless the property were `string[] FirstName`), As always use a view model.

Comment: You can not do that.Add an extra property in you model for firstname textbox

Comment: Ohh sad to know that this is hard for me to do because I am sending the whole model by using pure mvc at server side so I can not change model still I will try by doing some tricky way. thanks Stephen Muecke and Shashank Sood for the answer.

Comment: Is it possible to set that textbox value in FirstName of model by using javascript or jquery?

Comment: @padhiyar, Stop using a data model in a view. Always use a view model.

Comment: I can't understand view model? Can you give me one link please so I can view and use it!

Comment: [What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: Ohhh thank you again @StephenMuecke